# Storing firebase config in .env files

Tags: node.js, firebase, environment-variables, sveltekit

I have a Sveltekit project where I am using firebase for authentication. I am storing the firebase.js file which contains the config parameters like apiKey and authDomain in the \src\lib folder. I am storing the apiKey value in the .env file which is present at the root of the project and using the process.env.API_KEY to load the value for the same. However when I do npm run build I get an error in the browser console - "process is not defined". I tried the below approaches but none of them seem to work -

Approach 1 -

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { config } from 'dotenv'

config()

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)

export default auth
```

Approach 2 -

Here I used the env-cmd library which I found via another Stackoverflow post. Below is the updated code

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env['API_KEY'],
  authDomain: process.env['AUTH_DOMAIN'],
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)

export default auth
```

I also updated the scripts in package.json like below -

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "env-cmd vite dev",
        "build": "env-cmd vite build",
        "package": "svelte-kit package",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "prepare": "svelte-kit sync"
    }
```

Neither of the approaches seem to work and I still get the same error i.e. "process is not defined". Even some of the other repos I checked on Github had the apiKey hard coded in the config file, which obviously is a bad practice, even for hobby projects.

Any ideas on how I could incorporate the firebase apiKey via the .env file?

Answer (score 8):

From the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different)

> **Unlike how API keys are typically used, API keys for Firebase services are not used to control access to backend resources;** that can only be done with Firebase Security Rules (to control which users can access resources) and App Check (to control which apps can access resources).

> Usually, you need to fastidiously guard API keys (for example, by using a vault service or setting the keys as environment variables); however, **API keys for Firebase services are ok to include in code or checked-in config files.**

Answer (score 0):

Your `.env` file should have variables like this `VITE_SECURE_API_KEY=API-KEY`
and you can use them in your client-side app using `import.meta.env.VITE_SECURE_API_KEY`.

`dotenv` works on the server-side for sveltekit using node-adapter, also the firebase-admin package works only on the node environment.